# Display value instead of ID mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

When I add `$elan_category`, I get `category_id`, instead `category_title`.

Tried to apply "left join" but no success. I have following tables in database:

[image]

```
function getElanDetail()
{
    global $con;

    if (isset($_GET['elan_id'])) {

        $elan_id = $_GET['elan_id'];
        $get_elan = "select * from elan where elan_id='$elan_id'";
        $run_elan = mysqli_query($con, $get_elan);

        while ($row_elan = mysqli_fetch_array($run_elan)) {

            $elan_id = $row_elan['elan_id'];
            $elan_category = $row_elan['elan_category'];
            $elan_title = $row_elan['elan_title'];
            $elan_description = $row_elan['elan_description'];
            $elan_image = $row_elan['elan_image'];
            $elan_contact = $row_elan['elan_contact'];

            echo "
                $elan_category //Getting ID of category instead Title :(
                $elan_title
                $elan_description
                $elan_image
                $elan_contact
";

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Add a `"` to your echo.

Comment: yes, missed it while copying from ide

Comment: SO you told you use join. Where's the query with a join?

Comment: i couldn't make a "healthy" join query

Comment: @helgun you should still add the code that doesn't work, in the end that is the code you want help with - not this one that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `join` you can do something like:

```
$elan_id = $_GET['elan_id'];
$get_elan = "SELECT * FROM `elan` 
    JOIN `categories` ON `categories`.category_id = `elan`.elan_category 
    WHERE `elan`.elan_id='$elan_id'";
$run_elan = mysqli_query($con, $get_elan);
while ($row_elan=mysqli_fetch_array($run_elan)){
    print_r($row_elan);
    // see the keys in $row_elan and use them accordingly
}
```

For subcategories try this query:

```
SELECT * FROM `elan` 
JOIN `categories` ON `categories`.category_id = `elan`.elan_category        
JOIN `subcategories` ON `subcategories`.subcategory_id = `elan`.elan_subcategory 
WHERE `elan`.elan_id='$elan_id'
```

Comment: exactly what i needed. What if i have also "subcategory", how can i add it in query to see subcategories id,title also in row?

Comment: Also, for injection protection:  `$elan_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $elan_id)`

Comment: Updated answer according to your db scheme. As I don't know keys in `subcategories` table - change if needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
$elan_category = $row_elan['elan_category'];
```

add these two lines after above code

```
$cat = mysqli_fetch_row(mysqli_query($con,"SELECT category_title FROM categories WHERE category_id = $elan_category"));
$cat_name = $cat[0];
```

$cat_name is your category name enjoy